# Wii remote as ir signal detector

Tags: infrared, wii

Hi am currently looking at creating an IR remote control for a robot but i need something that i can use to monitor the signal so i was think that a wii remote has a IR cam in it so i can use that to report back to my pc the signal that my remote is generating.

anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not a good idea to do that with a $40 Wii remote, designed to track the position of IR emitters, not data signals. You could do it with a < $10. part such as http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=8554 . See also http://www.gumbolabs.org/2010/05/29/radioshack-infrared-receiver-arduino/

Comment: thanks for that ye I thought that a Infrared receiver was the way to go but I thought I would find out if my wii remote would work. what am basicly trying to do it create a IR remote for a robot i have created.

Comment: How is the robot connected to the computer? I'm confused about where you want the remote control... if the robot is controlled by the computer directly, you could use the Wiimote as the remote control, and a bluetooth receiver in the computer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a .net based SDK for the wiimote: http://wiimotelib.codeplex.com/
You can use the test program in the SDK to "see" the IR lights.
You will need a bluetooth adapter to communicate with the mote.